# passwd fails with passwd: pam_start() failed, error 26 in tahr puppy 6.0.2

Tags: pam, passwd, puppylinux

From the messages log:

```
Dec 17 08:08:28 puppypc30098 authpriv.err passwd[8265]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

The file /etc/pam.d/common-passwd is indeed missing:

```
root# ls /etc/pam.d
chfn  chpasswd  chsh  newusers  other  passwd  sshd
```

Is there a package that needs to be installed to get passwd to work?

Comment: I switched to lunbutu.  This and several other issues went away.

Answer (score 0):

create following code inside the file `/etc/pam.d/common-passwd`, then `passwd` works:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password    requisite   pam_deny.so           
password    required    pam_permit.so               
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so    
password    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? A good answer should have explanation so it's not just "Trust me, an anonymous stranger on the internet, to tell you how to configure passwords on my machine. What could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: Anyone curious about the above can check out `man 5 pam.d` or visit [the online man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d)